# Cursor to get the contacts returns null

Tags: android, android-contacts

In my application i want to fetch all the contacts from the phonebook.The code which i have written always gives me empty `cursor`

Code

//to get contacts in background

```
static class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<ContactsModel>> {
    private Context context;
    private ContentResolver contactResolver;
    private ContactsModel contactsModel;
    private List<String> listPhones = Collections.emptyList();
    private List<String> listEmails = Collections.emptyList();
    private List<ContactsModel> listContacts = Collections.emptyList();
    private String phone;
    private String email;
    private String id;
    private Cursor phoneCursor;
    private Cursor emailCursor;

    public GetContacts(Context context) {
        this.context = context;

    }

    @Override
    protected List<ContactsModel> doInBackground(Void... params) {

        contactResolver = context.getContentResolver();
        Cursor cur = contactResolver.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                null, null, null, null);
        if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
            while (cur.moveToNext()) {
                contactsModel = new ContactsModel();

                id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                contactsModel.name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

                if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {

                    phoneCursor = contactResolver.query(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                            null,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                            new String[]{id}, null);

                    while (phoneCursor.moveToNext()) {
                        // Do something with phones
                        int phoneType = phoneCursor.getInt(phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE));
                        String phoneNo = phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                        //you will get all phone numbers according to it's type as below switch case.
                        switch (phoneType) {
                            case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE:
                                phone = phoneNo;
                                break;
                            case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_HOME:
                                phone = phoneNo;
                                break;
                            case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_WORK:
                                phone = phoneNo;
                                break;
                            case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_WORK_MOBILE:
                                phone = phoneNo;
                                break;
                            case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_OTHER:
                                phone = phoneNo;
                                break;
                            default:
                                break;
                        }

                        listPhones.add(phone);
                    }


                    emailCursor = contactResolver.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI,
                            null,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[]{id}, null);

                    while (emailCursor.moveToNext()) {
                        //String emai = emailCursor.getString(emailCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
                        int type = emailCursor.getInt(emailCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE));
                        String s = (String) ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.getTypeLabel(context.getResources(), type, "");
                        listEmails.add(emailCursor.getString(emailCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA)));

                    }

                    listContacts.add(contactsModel);
                    emailCursor.close();
                    phoneCursor.close();


                }


            }


        }

        cur.close();


        return listContacts;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<ContactsModel> contactsModels) {


    }
}
```

//activity code

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.all_contact_list);
        init();

    }


    protected void init() {
        context = this;
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pb_all_contacts);
        new GetContacts(context).execute();


    }
```

I have more than 1000 contacts in my address book

```
P.S - I also have requested permission to read contact in manifest
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code as i seen your on `onPostExecute` method is empty.I think in  this method you must set your already populate `list`

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<ContactsModel> contactsModels) {
       listContacts = contactsModels;
    }
```

Because you retrive data from your phone in `doInBackground` but where you passed it ? Hope to help!

Comment: But i am not getting only any contacts

Comment: i dont undestend you very well sorry.. your  return listContacts at the end of your doInBAckground but this list isnt asign, i think mistake come from it , but i can be wrong.. in your doInBackground method if you log your list is it empty ?

Comment: In doInbackground if i run the debugger, its not  going inside if(cur.getCount>0)

Comment: did you try with Log ?

Comment: yup still the same thing

Answer (score 0):

You need to give projection while query to content provider.

```
String[] mProjection =
{
    UserDictionary.Words._ID,    // Contract class constant for the _ID column name
    UserDictionary.Words.WORD,   // Contract class constant for the word column name
    UserDictionary.Words.LOCALE  // Contract class constant for the locale column name
};


contactResolver = context.getContentResolver();
        Cursor cur = contactResolver.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                mProjection, null, null, null);
```

above is just an example of projection while query content provider.

you can refer this links,
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html
http://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/retrieve-details.html

Comment: projection A list of which columns to return. Passing null will return all columns, which is inefficient.